# Scala: how to copy part of a List to another List

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala.

I have a list
  origList = List[Double] with thousands of elements. 
I need to create another list 
  outList = List[Double] 
and copy to it the elements from origList with indices 
  start, start+1, ..., start+nCopy-1
that is the output list will have nCopy elements.

This part of the code will be executed many times. What is the most efficient way to do that in Scala?

Comment: You're looking for `slice`.  `List` may not be the best data structure either.

Answer (score 3):

The way people usually do it in scala is `list.slice(start, start+nCopy)`.

Note, that `List` in scala is *not* a random access container like `ArrayList` is in java. It is implemented as a linked list, so, especially, if you are going to do this many times, it will help significantly, if you convert your list to something indexed before hand: `val converted = list.toIndexedSeq` or, better, `val converted = list.toArray`.

`.slice` on an `Array` or on `IndexedSeq` will be much more efficient, especially if `start` index is high.

Now, if you are *really* concerned about efficiency, of this one operation, nothing (unfortunately) beats the good-old java approach:

```
val converted = list.toArray
val copied = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(converted, start, start+nCopy)
```

This can be *orders of magnitude* faster than `converted.slice` (leave alone `list.slice`)  when copying a large enough (hundreds) number of elements.

Comment: Could you please note why `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange` can be "orders of magnitude faster" than `converted#slice`? Lastly, looking at `Array#copyOfRange`'s docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)), one risk appears to be: `a new array containing the specified range from the original array, truncated or padded with nulls to obtain the required length`

Comment: It is faster because it is implemented (very) differently, using native code to copy a continuous chunk of memory at once, rather than moving elements one-by-one like scala implementation has it. If by "why" you mean "why it is not implemented the same way java has it", I have no idea. You'd have to ask whoever wrote the scala implementation. My guess is that it was easier. 
As to the "risk" part, I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Dima. By "risk", I only meant that `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Array(1,2,3), 0, 5)` === `Array(1, 2, 3, 0, 0)`. My naive assumption, was that the above would've equaled `Array(1,2,3)`, i.e. `null`'s would not pad. I suppose "read the docs" is an assumed task when using a method, but I did not, naively, expect the padded `null`'s.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Making "naive assumptions" is always risky, regardless of which concrete  implementation you end up using ;)

Comment: -1. The part about orders of magnitude slower is false. I tested on a `List` of length 10000. When copying elements 5000 to 6000 simple `List.slice` is twice faster then `Arrays.copyOfRange`. When copying elements 1000 to 9000 `List.slice` is twice slower. I believe the slowest part in `Arrays.copyOfRange` is copying the whole `List` to `Array` in the beginning. The `slice` being slower would be correct if there was an `Array` from the start.

Comment: @Kolmar Try reading a bit more carefully what I actually wrote: _you_ copy `List` to `Array` first, and _then_ use `Arrays.copyOfRange` multiple times. The statement about "orders of magnitude slower" was about comparing `Array.slice` to `Arrays.copyOfRange(array)`.